# How to get some value in column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a job Name column in the JobDetails table.like this

```
job Name

A_1
A_2
B_1
B_2
B_3
```

I search max number like this

```
SELECT MAX(JobDetails.[Job Name])
FROM Monara.JobDetails 
WHERE 
    ( [Job Name] like 'B_%' )
```

Result is B_3

But i want to get only 3.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refuse to make a column containing space(s)

Underscore is a wildchar that you should handle carefully when using *Like*

```
create table JobDetails ([JobName] varchar(10))
insert JobDetails values('A_1'),('A_2'),('B_1'),('B_2'),('B_3')

SELECT max(cast(stuff(JobName, 1, patindex('%[_]%', JobName), '') as int)) 
FROM JobDetails
WHERE JobName like 'B[_]%'
-- added check to prevent most bad data
and IsNumeric(stuff(JobName, 1, patindex('%[_]%', JobName), '')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(JobDetails.[Job Name],
                  ( SELECT  CHARINDEX('_', JobDetails.[Job Name])
                  ) + 1,
                  LEN(JobDetails.[Job Name]) - 
                  CHARINDEX('_', JobDetails.[Job Name])
                  + 1)
FROM    Monara.JobDetails
WHERE   [Job Name] LIKE 'B_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(JobDetails.[Job Name])
FROM Monara.JobDetails
WHERE [Job Name] like 'B_%'
```